# Openforcefield package import error occurs wiith missing 'GLIBCXX_3.4.26'

Tags: python, linux, google-colaboratory

I installed openmm package by miniconda with following code.
It was executed on colab

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
!wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-py37_4.10.3-Linux-x86_64.sh
!bash Miniconda3-py*.sh -bfp /usr/local
!conda config --set always_yes yes
!conda config --add channels conda-forge
!conda create -n openmm python=3.7 cudatoolkit=10.0 git jupyterlab numpy pandas scipy matplotlib ipympl rdkit openbabel openmm mdtraj pymbar pdbfixer parmed openff-toolkit openmoltools openmmforcefields
sys.path.append('/usr/local/envs/openmm/lib/python3.7/site-packages')
import openmm.testInstallation
openmm.testInstallation.main()
```

since openmm package contains openff package, the following code should be executed.

```
from openff.toolkit.topology import Molecule
from openforcefield.utils.toolkits import RDKitToolkitWrapper, AmberToolsToolkitWrapper
from openforcefield.topology import Topology
from openforcefield.typing.engines.smirnoff import ForceField
biar = Molecule.from_smiles('c1ccccc1-c1c(C)ccnc1')
#Gerates conformers, default number of generated conformers is 10.
biar.generate_conformers()
biar.compute_partial_charges_am1bcc()
```

I know that the 2nd-4th line have errors, however, the first line shouldn't have any problems.

The error was following.

```
ImportError: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.26' not found (required by /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/openmm/../../../libOpenMM.so.7.7)
```

I tried downgrading RDkit and adding GLIBCXX_3.4.26 by the following.

```
!add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
!apt-get update --fix-missing
!apt-get dist-upgrade
```

None of them was worked.

Is there any possible way to resolve this error?
I'm really frustrating now...

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this error by the following code!

````
import sys
import os
import requests
import subprocess
import shutil
from logging import getLogger, StreamHandler, INFO


logger = getLogger(__name__)
logger.addHandler(StreamHandler())
logger.setLevel(INFO)


def install(
        chunk_size=4096,
        file_name="Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh",
        url_base="https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/",
        conda_path=os.path.expanduser(os.path.join("~", "miniconda")),
        rdkit_version='2020.03.3',
        add_python_path=True,
        force=False):
    """install rdkit from miniconda
    ```
    import rdkit_installer
    rdkit_installer.install()
    ```
    """

    python_path = os.path.join(
        conda_path,
        "lib",
        "python{0}.{1}".format(*sys.version_info),
        "site-packages",
    )

    if add_python_path and python_path not in sys.path:
        logger.info("add {} to PYTHONPATH".format(python_path))
        sys.path.append(python_path)

    if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(python_path, "rdkit")):
        logger.info("rdkit is already installed")
        if not force:
            return

        logger.info("force re-install")

    url = url_base + file_name
    python_version = "{0}.{1}.{2}".format(*sys.version_info)

    logger.info("python version: {}".format(python_version))

    if os.path.isdir(conda_path):
        logger.warning("remove current miniconda")
        shutil.rmtree(conda_path)
    elif os.path.isfile(conda_path):
        logger.warning("remove {}".format(conda_path))
        os.remove(conda_path)

    logger.info('fetching installer from {}'.format(url))
    res = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    res.raise_for_status()
    with open(file_name, 'wb') as f:
        for chunk in res.iter_content(chunk_size):
            f.write(chunk)
    logger.info('done')

    logger.info('installing miniconda to {}'.format(conda_path))
    subprocess.check_call(["bash", file_name, "-b", "-p", conda_path])
    logger.info('done')

    logger.info("installing rdkit")
    subprocess.check_call([
        os.path.join(conda_path, "bin", "conda"),
        "install",
        "--yes",
        "-c", "rdkit",
        "python==3.7.9",
        "rdkit" if rdkit_version is None else "rdkit=={}".format(rdkit_version)])
    logger.info("done")

    import rdkit
    logger.info("rdkit-{} installation finished!".format(rdkit.__version__))


install()
````

but still, biar.compute_partial_charges_am1bcc() function does not work...